# Salesforce disabled TLS 1.0 encryption

Tags: api, encryption, external-app, tls

Could you please help me with this issue? Actually SF uses TLS 1.0 encryption for the communication between the external app and the platform. But regarding to the last communication of SF this protocol will be disabled soon and the new version to use will be the TLS 1.1.
Do you know if the customer needs to make some update in its external Apps? I was investigating for more information about this on the SF web, but we have only a mail from SF to the customer about the future change.

Comment: If the external application does not use tls 1.1 or higher then yes it will need updated. The impact should have a small footprint but it is possible there are still systems that do not have the ability to use 1.1 or higher. You will have to contact the vendor for the external system to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the email in detail, the mail says that we need to confirm with all the integration systems about their compliance on TLS 1.1 and above.
This would include
- Third party apps connecting to Salesforce
- Your Company ERP connecting to Salesforce
- Any other integration points to SFDC both Inbound and Outbound.

Along with that, please work with you Security team about all Browsers compliance with the TLS 1.1 and above protocol.